# How to convert 'node index.js' to a CLI name?

Tags: node.js

I am building a node script. I want to convert this

```
node index.js "hello"
```

to

```
Test "hello"
```

How can I do this? Tried with `npm link` and `yarn link` but no luck.

Comment: If you are working with mac or ubuntu you can add alias in bashrc file.
- vi ~/.bash_aliases
- alias Test = 'command to go to the directory and then node index.js with argument'

Comment: You need to make the script executable `chmod +x index.js` and add a shebang as first line `#!/usr/bin/node`